# puppeteer - Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a page - https://www.100chui.com/resume/ for a list of titles.

[image]

as seen in the image above, the scraping selector looks very simple to implement by simply using 'ul li' or '.content .template_ul_li';
'

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'https://www.100chui.com/resume/';
const selector = 'ul li';

(async function(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector(selector)
    const articles = await page.$$eval(selector, nodes => {
        return  nodes.map( node => {            
            let title = node.querySelector('.desc a').textContent.trim();
            title = title.replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ", ");
            return {
                title,
            }
        })
    });
    console.log(articles);
    await browser.close();
})();

// I even used this line to wait the selector to render
await page.waitForSelector(selector)
```

i don't see the problem with my code, but wondering why it is not working at all.

Error message:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:4:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:23
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (/Users/Documents/code/server/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:247:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/Users/Documents/code/server/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:125:16)
    at async JSHandle.evaluate (/Users/xisizhe/Documents/code/server/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/JSHandle.js:89:16)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ElementHandle.$$eval (/Users/Documents/code/server/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ElementHandle.js:208:26)
```

Comment: Please include the full error message

Comment: @Phil the error message is added

Answer (score 0):

Your base selector is a very general `ul li` which includes other lists than the one with the `.desc` elements in it. For example, if you run that in dev tools, you'll see it picks up the navigation elements.

If you want just the `.desc a` elements, make that your top-level selector (optionally nested in `ul li` like `ul li .desc a` if you want to make it more specific):

```js
const articles = await page.$$eval(".desc a", nodes =>
  nodes.map(node => ({
    title: node.textContent.trim()
  }))
);
```

I removed `.replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ", ")` because it doesn't have any bearing on the output here. It's easy enough to add back in if it's useful for you on other pages.

Also, [you may not need Puppeteer here](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-puppeteer-when-other-tools-are-more-appropriate), since the data is available in the static HTML. Adding

```js
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

gives a significant speed increase and helps verify this. Consider switching to `fetch` and Cheerio, or another HTTP request library and HTML parser.